# Last message translated into 'False parameter' when creating a RenderTarget2D

Tags: c#, directx, sharpdx

Summarization: Making a fade effect for a game of mine, suddenly get this error message:

An unhandled exception of type `SharpDX.SharpDXException` occurred in SharpDX.dll

Additional information:

```
HRESULT: [0x80070057], Module: [General], ApiCode: [E_INVALIDARG/Invalid Arguments], Message: Felaktig parameter. (Last message translated into False Paramater
```

Tutorial I am watching: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=krQZqPO0arQ

```
    renderTarget = new RenderTarget2D(Game1.graphics.GraphicsDevice, (int)dimensions.X, (int)dimensions.Y);
```

Comment: We need a lot more information than one line of code to help you :). What are the values of `Game1.graphics.GraphicsDevice`, `(int)dimensions.X`, and `(int)dimensions.Y` when you type them in the watch window or hover over them with the mouse?

Comment: In order: {Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.GraphicsDevice}
0,0
0,0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a render target with invalid dimensions. You cannot create a render target with a width or height of 0. If you think about it this makes sense. A width or height of 0 would mean there is space for 0 pixels in the render target, so you can't draw anything to it.

To solve this make sure that the vector `dimension` is initialized somewhere. Usually a render target is the same size as the resolution the game is running at. However, it is also possible that the render target is used for something else. In which case it needs other dimensions.

Comment: Great to hear that :)